# How do I get the menlo font onto Google Docs?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, font-design, google

I want to get the menlo font onto Google docs but it's not in Google fonts.
It looks like this:

```
The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.
```

However, it's not available. I need it because that's what the <kbd>F12</kbd> console defaults to and I'm writing a book about JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Menlo is not a supported font for Google Docs. There is a nice alternative that could get the job done called [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata), and since it's a Google font it's really simple to access in docs:

[image]

Here's how Google describes it:

> It is a monospace font, designed for printed code listings and the
>   like. There are a great many “programmer fonts,” designed primarily
>   for use on the screen, but in most cases do not have the attention to
>   detail for high resolution rendering. Inconsolata draws from many
>   inspirations and sources. I was particularly struck by the beauty of
>   Luc(as) de Groot's Consolas, which is his monospaced design for
>   Microsoft's Vista release. This font, similar to his earlier
>   TheSansMono, demonstrated clearly to me that monospaced fonts do not
>   have to suck.

---

**Installation**

To access this font in Google docs, <kbd>click</kbd> the dropdown menu to reveal the document font list and <kbd>click</kbd> the **More Fonts...** option at the bottom of the list:

[image]

Then just search for "Inconsolata" and add it to your list by clicking the font name. <kbd>Click</kbd> **OK** to append the selected fonts to your document font list:

[image]